# Do functions w/pointer arguments still have local copies of those arguments?

Tags: c

Consider the following code taken from K&R:

```
/* strlen: return length of string s */

int strlen(char *s)
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; *s != '\0', s++)
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

K&R states that here "s++ has no effect on the character string in the function that called strlen, but merely increments strlen's private copy of the pointer".

1. Am I correct in interpreting "s++" as being equivalent to "&s[0]+1".  This seems non-sensical to me, so I must be wrong here.
2. If s++ *really* has no effect on *s, then how could the loop condition (i.e., *s != '\0') ever change in truth value?  After all, *s is *unaffected* by s++.  So it will either be true forever or false in the first place.  Why is this not the case?

Comment: you are going to have to play around in the debugger / printf's to really prove this to yourself

Comment: A copy of the pointer, yes.

Comment: Yes, arguments are always copied in C.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in interpreting "s++" as being equivalent to "&s[0]+1".

No. The expression `&s[0]+1` does not have side-effects - `s++` does. The way it is used here (that is without using its return value), `s++` is equivalent to `s = s + 1` or `s = &s[0]+1` or `s = &s[1]` (which all do the same thing).

> If s++ really has no effect on *s, then how could the loop condition (i.e., *s != '\0') ever change in truth value?

`s++` does have an effect on `*s` in the sense that it changes what `s` points to and if `s` points to somewhere else, then of course the value of the expression `*s` will change. However it does not have an effect on the value that `s` previously pointed to.

To illustrate this consider `strlen` being called on a string `str` where `char* str = "abcd";`: At the beginning of the loop `s` points to `str[0]`and thus `*s` is equal to 'a' because `str[0]` is equal to `'a'`. After you do `s++`, `s` now points to `str[1]`. Now `*s` is equal to `'b'` because `str[1]` is equal to `'b'`, yet neither `str[0]` nor the contents of `str` changed.

Comment: @user1770201 Yes, that's correct - in my example `s` would be a copy of `str`, both containing the address of the `'a'` in "abcd" (until `s` is incremented, after which it contains the address of the `'b'` and so on), but both having their own address themselves (that is `&s != &str`).

Answer (score 1):

A copy of the pointer, yes. Arguments are always copied. And the same way a function can modify arguments as its own local variables without affecting the original variable, the same can be done with pointers.

By incrementing `s++` you are doing the same as `s = &s[1]` or `s = s + 1`, and it modifies `s` as the local variable it is, this change does not propagate to the original pointer in the caller.

Only by modifying the value a pointer is pointing to, as when modifying `*s`, it will have it modified in the caller aswell. Thats why when attempting to modify a pointer itself, you have to use a pointer to a pointer, for instance: `char** var`